# SELECT Statement in SQL for filtering out multiple entries

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to query how many different accounts are linked to one price.

```
name           | price | acc_no

Allnet Flat S  | 14.99 |   1
Allnet Flat XL | 24.99 |   2
Data Flat XL   | 14.99 |   2
Data Flat S    |  9.99 |   1
Family Flat S  | 29.99 |   3
Family Flat XXL| 59.99 |   4
SMS Flat S     |  9.99 |   1
```

My closest solution is a

```
SELECT price, COUNT(acc_no) FROM "table" GROUP BY price
```

The problem here is that it shows me two accounts linked to 9.99, although it is the same account number. How can I make it count the same account only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` in the `COUNT` function:

```
SELECT price, COUNT(DISTINCT account_no) FROM "table" GROUP BY price
--                  ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: In this case the 14.99 shows only one account, but there are two

Comment: @Jan - This query works correctly showing 2 accounts for 14.99 and 1 for the rest

Comment: Jan, I created a test table with the exact same content as you posted in your example, and it properly showed 2 accounts with $14.99.

Comment: @Jan This works fine for me ([demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/89207/3)).

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped something. It is correct. Thank you!